# Not able to set older date then current if minDate property is set to moment() using Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

My requirement is i don't want allow user to select past date from the date picker (this was done using `minDate: moment()`). But i must have to show the past date in textbox as well as in datepicker dropdown.

For example, Today is 23 Oct 2017, So i am able to select any date from today and future. But few dates that were already in past (i.e. 03 Mar 2017, 12 Nov 2016) in that case **those dates were not shown in the textbox it was automatically cleared due to** `minDate: moment()` **feature is set. If i remove this property then i am able to show that date**.

This issue i was facing after **migrating Bootstrap Version 3.0.0 to 4.17.42**.
Following is the code:

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        defaultDate: moment(GetCurrentDate(), "DD-MM-YYYY"),
        minDate: moment()           //set a minimum date
});
```

Using this DateTimePicker: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you must set as option `keepInvalid: true` as by default [`keepInvalid`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keepinvalid) is false, that way the `minDate` option won't overwrite the date before.

This way any Date that was before on the picker should stay there.

So your code should look like:

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    defaultDate: moment(GetCurrentDate(), "DD-MM-YYYY"),
    minDate: moment(),           //set a minimum date
    keepInvalid: true,
});
```

Now in case you're not using `minDate` option you must set `useCurrent: false` that way won't be problems.

> This issue i was facing after migrating Bootstrap Version 3.0.0 to 4.17.42

I advise you to upgrade to the latest Version [4.17.47](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js) some fixes has been made

Comment: Perfect, now i can see the past date in the textbox (using keepInvalid: true option). **But the issue is when i click on picker icon, calendar popup will not show that date selected, it is showing current date as a selected.**

Comment: That's because of `defaultDate` but if you set default date to your last date this will throw a [TypeError as per documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#defaultdate) and `minDate` will overwrite that selection, and currently I don't have a workaorund for that